# Playwright | azure pipeline- getting error while running tests in ms edge browser

Tags: azure-pipelines, microsoft-edge, playwright, playwright-test

I usually run the tests on chrome browser as base platform. Occassionally i will do cross browser testing on Firefox and MS edge browsers locally. After configuring to pipeline i ran cross browser testing, but I got a failure for ms edge browser to install browser properly as

```
 Error: browserType.launch: Chromium distribution 'msedge' is not found at C:\Users\tfs-build\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
    Run "npx playwright install msedge".
```

After adding installation cmd in execution file I'm getting error as:

```
Downloading Microsoft Edge
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure 
channel."
At C:\agent2\_work\16\s\node_modules\playwright-core\bin\reinstall_msedge_stable_win.ps1:8 char:1
+ $wc.Downloadfile($url, $msiInstaller)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
 
Failed to install browsers
Error: Failed to install msedge
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, it seems that on your environment PowerShell uses TLS 1.0 when connecting to websites by default but the site you are making a request to requires TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 or SSLv3.

To solve the error, just try using the `SecurityProtocol` property to specify that all protocols are supported.

Just add the following at the top of your script or before your installation cmd and then try it again.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "Tls, Tls11, Tls12, Ssl3"
```

Comment: Thank you, Andy. I will implement your suggestions and keep you posted on the results.

Comment: @VINAYM Yeah, please have a try for that, any results please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @VINAYM May I know any update? Have you resolved the issue by the solution?

Comment: Apology for late response. Initially the above cmd not worked for me. Later i did few configuration for that i followed the below steps:

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to enable the Tls1.2
For Windows:
Open Registry Editor:
Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
Type regedit and press Enter.
Navigate to the Registry Key:
Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319.
If the key SchUseStrongCrypto doesn't exist, you may need to create it.
Create or Modify the Registry Key:
Right-click in the right-hand pane, select New, and then choose DWORD (32-bit) Value.
Name it SchUseStrongCrypto.
Double-click on it and set the value to 1.
Restart the Machine:
Restart your machine for the changes to take effect.
NOTE: Modifying the registry should be done with caution, and you should have the appropriate permissions to make changes.

Comment: Yes, your solution helped me to resolve my issue. Thanks a lot.